# SSAS Tabular Model on Azure VM

Tags: ssas, azure-virtual-machine, msbi, ssas-tabular

I have an Azure VM with SSAS Tabular Model.
I understand that using Virtual Network it can be accessed from On-Premise.
But is it possible to access it using DAX queries without creating Virtual Network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: No - you need a Virtual Network in this scenario ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156007.aspx))

**Long answer**: Maybe. It might be possible to use [HTTP Access to SSAS via IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx) but I've never tried it nor have I come across any blogs/whitepapers where it has been tried.

Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid setting one up? It really does make things much easier in Azure.

Comment: I tried HTTP Access to SSAS via IIS after posting this question. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

we use an HTTP proxy 
Just set up as normal but remember to configure an endpoint on the TCP and SSAS ports in AZURE